# How to retrieve XML using guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle6, guzzle

I want to retrieve a response from a certain url but this URL return it's response using xml. Is there a way to retrieve this response using Guzzle? In Guzzle 5.3 we could easily do something like

> $response->xml()

Thus this will parse the xml content. Now when I tried to use the same code in Guzzle 6.2 it's not working anymore. Below is my code

```
$response = $client->get($this->url);
$resp = $response->xml();
```

But this does not work. I also tried below

```
$response = $client->get($this->url);
$response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$responseXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
if ($responseXml instanceof \SimpleXMLElement)
{
   $key_value = (string)$responseXml->key_name;
   return $key_value;
 }
```

But this does not work. Any idea on how to retrieve the xml data?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Sorry got it figured out. Will post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out. It turns out I just need to add

> 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'

to the header parameters of my request. Then I can just decode the xml as shown in the code below

```
$provider_type = 'application/xml';

$param_data = [
   'headers' => [
      'Accept' => $provider_type,
   ]
];
$response = $this->client->get($this->url, $param_data);            
$response = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    switch ($provider_type) {
        case 'application/xml':
            $encode_response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response));   

            $decode_response = json_decode($encode_response, TRUE);
            return $decode_response;

        default: // Response json
            $encode_response = json_encode($response);   

            $decode_response = json_decode($encode_response, TRUE);
            return json_decode($decode_response, TRUE);                

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're going from xml to json to associative array... Might want to take a look at xpath.  Really great way to extract data from xml.  xpath provides a system of element selectors kinda like css selectors isolate nodes.

Comment: @TarekAdam yeah the real aim here is to create a single class that can handle any endpoint without having to change code when data provider response changes. If the endpoint change to xml the class should be able to support it and no impact with the code. The solution I thought was from XML convert it back to JSOn and then to associative array that way the implementation is same with a data provider with json response